# powershell sharepoint item column

Tags: list, powershell

I am searching a list and I want to print out a certain part of the item.
I can do it using

```
select web |
select list |
Select items |
select Name
```

just wondering how can I do it like

```
$site = get site
foreach allwebs
foreach list2
$list2.items["Name"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
# Start-SPAssignment will automatically dispose the $site and $web when we hit Stop-SPAssignment
Start-SPAssignment -Global

# Load SharePoint Module if it has not already been loaded
If ((Get-PSSnapin | Where { $_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" } | Select -First 1) -eq $null)
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

# Enter your site where it says 'http://site'
$siteUrl = 'http://site'
$site = Get-SPSite $siteUrl
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    foreach ($list in $web.Lists)
    {
        $items = $list.Items
        $items | Select Name
    }
}

Stop-SPAssignment -Global
```

If you know beforehand the specific SPWeb Url, you can load it directly by `$web = Get-SPWeb 'http://site/web'` and if you know the title of the list, you can grab it directly by `$list = $web.Lists['Shared Documents']`

Answer (score 0):

The following script iterates through all webs and prints item values for a specific list:

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
    Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

$siteUrl = "http://contoso.intranet.com/"
$listTitle = "Tasks"
$fieldName = "Title"

Get-SPSite $siteUrl | 
Get-SPWeb -Limit All |
Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
Where { $_.Title -eq $listTitle } |
Select -ExpandProperty Items |
Select {$_[$fieldName]}
```